# How can I refactor duplicate jquery validation methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

In my rails app I have this jquery validate code in a js.erb file that loads when the page loads.

```
  if ($('#custom-tag').length) {
    $('#custom-tag').validate({
      onfocusout: false,
      rules: {
        tag: {
          minLengthSquish: 2,
          maxLengthSquish: 25
        }
      },
      tooltip_options: {
        tag: { placement: 'right', animation: false }
      }
    });
  }
```

The form is there on page load but the user is able to add and remove tags through ajax request.  With each request the form is re-rendered because the form will only display if the tag count is 5 or less, so I need to reinitialize jquery validate each time the form loads.  This same exact code exists in my add_tag.js.erb and remove_tag.js.erb files which are called from the controller through ajax.

I'm just wondering if having this duplicate code in three places is the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure having duplicate code in three places isn't the only way to accomplish this. Maybe consider putting the code in a single location and reference it in the three places it's actually required.

Comment: or add this code as event listener for the page load event and ajax:complete or something like it.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The form is there on page load but the user is able to add and remove tags through ajax request. With each request the form is re-rendered because the form will only display if the tag count is 5 or less, **so I need to reinitialize jquery validate** each time the form loads.

You **cannot** *"reinitialize"* jQuery Validate on the same form.  Subsequent calls to `.validate()` are always ignored.

Whenever you change the form you can [use the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to dynamically `add` and `remove` rules.

```
// on page load
$('#custom-tag').validate({ // initialize plugin on the form; can only be done once
    // options, etc.
    onfocusout: false,
    rules: {   // initial rules
        tag: {
            minLengthSquish: 2,
            maxLengthSquish: 25
        }
    }
});

// make changes dynamically
$('.newfields').each(function() { // add rules to multiple fields
    $(this).rules('add', {
        minLengthSquish: 5,
        maxLengthSquish: 50
    });
});

$('[name="tag"]').rules('add', {  // add rules to one field
    minLengthSquish: 30,
    maxLengthSquish: 55
});

$('[name="tag"]').rules('remove');  // remove all rules from one field
```

Comment: Thanks!  The solution worked but I don't get why.  jQuery validate is initialized when the page loads initially and all works fine.  But if I re-render the form I need to add the same exact rules which were there with the initialization for it to work again.

Comment: Is there a way I can re-add the onfocusout:false property to the re-rendered form.  It seems to get reset to true.

Comment: @user4584963, no... the developer does not provide a method to reinitialize the plugin with new options.

Comment: How come the initialization persists but the options don't?  Just the way it was written?

Comment: @user4584963, good question and I do not know.  You may want to ask that part in the developer's GitHub forum.